# Fail to verify RSASSA-PSS signature across Python -> Go

Tags: python, go, rsa, digital-signature, pycrypto

I've boiled this down to the simplest test case I can. I need to take RSASSA-PSS signatures that were generated in Python and validate them in Go. The Python code to create the RSA keypair and sign with it is as follows:

```
>>> from tuf import pycrypto_keys as k
>>> pub, priv = k.generate_rsa_public_and_private()
>>> sig, method = k.create_rsa_signature(priv, "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
>>> sig.encode("hex")
'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'
```

The pycrypto_keys library referenced there can be found [here](https://github.com/theupdateframework/tuf/blob/develop/tuf/pycrypto_keys.py) for reference of the specific implementation of the functions `generate_rsa_public_and_private` and `create_rsa_signature`.

My Go test consists of 2 simple files that only rely on core packages. First the verification function, in verify.go:

```
package example

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
)

func Verify(key []byte, sig []byte, msg []byte) error {
    digest := sha256.Sum256(msg)

    pub, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to parse key")
    }

    rsaPub, ok := pub.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("Invalid value returned from ParsePKIXPublicKey")
    }

    opts := rsa.PSSOptions{SaltLength: 16, Hash: crypto.SHA256}
    if err = rsa.VerifyPSS(rsaPub, crypto.SHA256, digest[:], sig, &opts); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed Verification")
    }
    return nil
}
```

And second, a test case. The key pair and signature were generated using the Python commands at the top and copied in here to create a static set of parameters to use for compatibility testing.

```
package example

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/pem"
    "testing"
)

func TestPyCryptoRSACompatVerify(t *testing.T) {
    pubPem := "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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\n1ANMFPxDQpHudCLxwCzjCb+sVa20HBRPTnzo8LSZkI6jAgMBAAE=\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    //privPem := "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIG4wIBAAKCAYEAnKuXZeefa2LmgxaL5NsMzKOHNe+x/nL6ik+lDBCTV6OdcwAh\nHQS+PONGhrChIUVR6Vth3hUCrreLzPO73Oo5VSCuRJ53UronENl6lsa5mFKP8StY\nLvIDITNvkoT3j52BJIjyNUK9UKY9As2TNqDfBEPIRp28ev/NViwGOEkBu2UAbwCI\ndnDXm8JQErCZA0Ydm7PKGgjLbFsFGrVzqXHK6pdzJXlhr9yap3UpgQ/iO9JtoEYB\n2EXsnSrPc9JRjR30bNHHtnVql3fvinXrAEwq3xmN4p+R4VGzfdQN+8Kl/IPjqWB5\n35twhFYEG/B7Ze8IwbygBjK3co/KnOPqMUrMBI8ztvPiogz+MvXb8WvarZ6TMTh8\nifZI96r7zzqyzjR1hJulEy3IsMGvz8XS2J0X7sXoaqszEtXdq5ef5zKVxkiyIQZc\nbPgmpHLq4MgfdryuVVc/RPASoRIXG4lKaTJj1ANMFPxDQpHudCLxwCzjCb+sVa20\nHBRPTnzo8LSZkI6jAgMBAAECggGAdzyI7z/HLt2IfoAsXDLynNRgVYZluzgawiU3\ngeUjnnGhpSKWERXJC2IWDPBk0YOGgcnQxErNTdfXiFZ/xfRlSgqjVwob2lRe4w4B\npLr+CZXcgznv1VrPUvdolOSp3R2Mahfn7u0qVDUQ/g8jWVI6KW7FACmQhzQkPM8o\ntLGrpcmK+PA465uaHKtYccEB02ILqrK8v++tknv7eIZczrsSKlS1h/HHjSaidYxP\n2DAUiF7wnChrwwQEvuEUHhwVgQcoDMBoow0zwHdbFiFO2ZT54H2oiJWLhpR/x6RK\ngM1seqoPH2sYErPJACMcYsMtF4Tx7b5c4WSj3vDCGb+jeqnNS6nFC3aMnv75mUS2\nYDPU1heJFd8pNHVf0RDejLZZUiJSnXf3vpOxt9Xv2+4He0jeMfLV7zX0mO2Ni3MJ\nx6PiVy4xerHImOuuHzSla5crOq2ECiAxd1wEOFDRD2LRHzfhpk1ghiA5xA1qwc7Z\neRnkVfoy6PPZ4lZakZTm0p8YCQURAoHBAMUIC/7vnayLae7POmgy+np/ty7iMfyd\nV1eO6LTO21KAaGGlhaY26WD/5LcG2FUgc5jKKahprGrmiNLzLUeQPckJmuijSEVM\nl/4DlRvCo867l7fLaVqYzsQBBdeGIFNiT+FBOd8atff87ZBEfH/rXbDi7METD/VR\n4TdblnCsKYAXEJUdkw3IK7SUGERiQZIwKXrH/Map4ibDrljJ71iCgEureU0DBwcg\nwLftmjGMISoLscdRxeubX5uf/yxtHBJeRwKBwQDLjzHhb4gNGdBHUl4hZPAGCq1V\nLX/GpfoOVObW64Lud+tI6N9GNua5/vWduL7MWWOzDTMZysganhKwsJCY5SqAA9p0\nb6ohusf9i1nUnOa2F2j+weuYPXrTYm+ZrESBBdaEJPuj3R5YHVujrBA9Xe0kVOe3\nne151A+0xJOI3tX9CttIaQAsXR7cMDinkDITw6i7X4olRMPCSixHLW97cDsVDRGt\necO1d4dP3OGscN+vKCoL6tDKDotzWHYPwjH47sUCgcEAoVI8WCiipbKkMnaTsNsE\ngKXvO0DSgq3k5HjLCbdQldUzIbgfnH7bSKNcBYtiNxjR7OihgRW8qO5GWsnmafCs\n1dy6a/2835id3cnbHRaZflvUFhVDFn2E1bCsstFLyFn3Y0w/cO9yzC/X5sZcVXRF\nit3R0Selakv3JZckru4XMJwx5JWJYMBjIIAc+miknWg3niL+UT6pPun65xG3mXWI\nS+yC7c4rw+dKQ44UMLs2MDHRBoxqi8T0W/x9NkfDszpjAoHAclH7S4ZdvC3RIR0L\nLGoJuvroGbwx1JiGdOINuooNwGuswge2zTIsJi0gN/H3hcB2E6rIFiYid4BrMrwW\nmSeq1LZVS6siu0qw4p4OVy+/CmjfWKQD8j4k6u6PipiK6IMk1JYIlSCr2AS04JjT\njgNgGVVtxVt2cUM9huIXkXjEaRZdzK7boA60NCkIyGJdHWh3LLQdW4zg/A64C0lj\nIMoJBGuQkAKgfRuh7KI6Q6Qom7BM3OCFXdUJUEBQHc2MTyeZAoHAJdBQGBn1RFZ+\nn75AnbTMZJ6Twp2fVjzWUz/+rnXFlo87ynA18MR2BzaDST4Bvda29UBFGb32Mux9\nOHukqLgIE5jDuqWjy4B5eCoxZf/OvwlgXkX9+gprGR3axn/PZBFPbFB4ZmjbWLzn\nbocn7FJCXf+Cm0cMmv1jIIxej19MUU/duq9iq4RkHY2LG+KrSEQIUVmImCftXdN3\n/qNP5JetY0eH6C+KRc8JqDB0nvbqZNOgYXOfYXo/5Gk8XIHTFihm\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
    testStr := "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
    sigHex := "4e05ee9e435653549ac4eddbc43e1a6868636e8ea6dbec2564435afcb0de47e0824cddbd88776ddb20728c53ecc90b5d543d5c37575fda8bd0317025fc07de62ee8084b1a75203b1a23d1ef4ac285da3d1fc63317d5b2cf1aafa3e522acedd366ccd5fe4a7f02a42922237426ca3dc154c57408638b9bfaf0d0213855d4e9ee621db204151bcb13d4dbb18f930ec601469c992c84b14e9e0b6f91ac9517bb3b749dd117e1cbac2e4acb0e549f44558a2005898a226d5b6c8b9291d7abae0d9e0a16858b89662a085f74a202deb867acab792bdbd2c36731217caea8b17bd210c29b890472f11e5afdd1dd7b69004db070e04201778f2c49f5758643881403d45a58d08f51b5c63910c6185892f0b590f191d760b669eff2464456f130239bba94acf54a0cb98f6939ff84ae26a37f9b890be259d9b5d636f6eb367b53e895227d7d79a3a88afd6d28c198ee80f6527437c5fbf63accb81709925c4e03d1c9eaee86f58e4bd1c669d6af042dbd412de0d13b98b1111e2fadbe34b45de52125e9a"
    testKey, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pubPem))

    sigBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(sigHex)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = Verify(testKey.Bytes, sigBytes, []byte(testStr))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The code fails in the final check of the Verify function, outputting the error `Failed verification`. I've had a look at the Go PSS verification code and if anything goes wrong, a generic verification error is returned so it's not that helpful. Even if it was more specific, either there is a compatibility problem here, a bug in one of the language implementations, or my code is wrong.

Much thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but in the `Failed verification` case, you don't ever seem to inspect the error value from `VerifyPSS`.  Does it give you any additional information?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge "I've had a look at the Go PSS verification code and if anything goes wrong, a generic verification error is returned so it's not that helpful." There is a single verification error that gets returned in all cases with no additional context.

Comment: Perhaps the text message to sign is differently encoded in those context. I. that case the signed bytes would differ from those verified against. You might try signing known byte arrays first.

Comment: @mkl interesting idea. I've just tried a number of different representations and continue to get consistent failing results. I specifically chose characters in the 7 bit ASCII range to keep things simple so I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears I misinterpreted `_SALT_SIZE` in the Python code. With some help from the TUF developers (i.e. they told me) I discovered **PyCrypto's RSA PSS code infers the salt size to be equal to the size of the hash digest of the hashing algorithm in use**. In this case it was 32 bytes as the hashing algorithm was Sha256. With just the change of `opts := rsa.PSSOptions{SaltLength: 32, Hash: crypto.SHA256}` the code works.